# Performance of angular2 application hosted on firebase hosting

Tags: performance, angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have an angular2 application hosted on firebase hosting. I playing around with the application and checking the performance and saw the below network graph in chrome.

[image: Network capture]

There seems to be a gap of 1700ms without any activity after loading a few of the files. Is this a correct behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the graph here?

Comment: Updated. imaged embedded. :)

Comment: Posting performance data from your system and your site is not very useful. If you want a comparison: share a link that we can go to. If you want to know if you code is making things slow: share the minimal code that allows us to reproduce the problem.